# How to convert a cell array of struct to a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell-array

I have a cell array of such:

```
data{1}.field1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
data{2}.field1 = [7 8 9 10];
...

data{1}.field2 = {[1 2 3]; [4 5 6]};
data{2}.field2 = {[7 8 9]};
...
```

I there a simple trick to convert that so I have:

```
field1 = {[1 2 3 4 5 6], [7 8 9 10], ...}
field2 = {{[1 2 3];[4 5 6]},  {[7 8 9]}, ...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution that seem to work

```
tmp = [data{:}]; 
field1 = {tmp.field1}; 
field2 = {tmp.field2};`
```

Comment: You should accept your answer if you're satisfied with it, to make it clear that this is not an open question.